# t3 link custom TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

Is it possible some way to make a custom t3:// link?

I mean like this `'t3://page?uid=80'`

But then for a custom extension like:

```
't3://customextension_record?uid=123'
```

Directing to the detail view of my extension showing record 123

First thing to configure is this I think? :

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['typolinkBuilder']['customextension_record'] = '\CustomExt\CustomLinkbuilder::class'
```

Comment: When you just want to link a record you can use these instructions: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/LinkBrowser/Linkhandler/RecordLinkHandler.html#recordlinkhandler

Comment: Solved it that way, thanks alot